# Django - ошибка с датой

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

При попытке ввести команду `python manage.py makemigrations` выскакивает ошибка:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Это странно, потому что значение по умолчанию у меня везде есть:

```
import datetime

import django
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'article'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    # Метод для корректного отображения заголовков статей
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def getSmallText(self):
        if len(self.text) > 200:
            return self.text[:200]
        else:
            return self.text


class Comment(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'comment'

    text = models.TextField(default=None)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

Что же делать ?

Comment: В качестве веременной меры можно проблемным полям разрешить NULL, а потом все такие поля заполнить запросом из БД напрямую.

Comment: Покажите полный стактрейс. Попробуйте запустить с параметром --verbosity=3

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте проверить что у Вас в django settings.py указанна правильная тайм зона и вы получаете значения:

```
django.utils.timezone.now
```

Comment: У меня TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' стоит, это правильно ?